# Django 1.9 + Passenger on Dreamhost: Web application could not be started

Tags: python, django, passenger, dreamhost

I'm trying to use Django 1.9 (With Python 3.4) on Dreamhost shared hosting.

I followed this tutorial:
https://brobin.me/blog/2015/03/deploying-django-with-virtualenv-on-dreamhost/

And now my passenger_wsgi.py is like this:

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/my_project')

INTERP = os.path.expanduser("~/venv/bin/python")

if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "my_project.settings"
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The problem is the Passenger startup, when I go to the site, Passenger is showing this error:

```
Web application could not be started

An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.

Raw process output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dh/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 320, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/dh/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 61, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 312, in execl
    execv(file, args)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm really not understanding how Passenger works, I think the problem is related with [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phusion-passenger/cYBgUPX_ICA/76T0-iDID4AJ) but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the correct settings in the passenger_wsgi.py:

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
project_location = cwd + '/my_project'
sys.path.insert(0,project_location)

INTERP = os.path.expanduser("/home/user/python/Python-3.4.3/venv/bin/python")

if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/python/Python-3.4.3/venv/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/python/Python-3.4.3/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/python/Python-3.4.3/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages')


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "my_project.settings"
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Are you running this on DreamHost VPS or what other product?

Comment: Hi! Dreamhost Shared Hosting